# mongoose get relative data without query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this two schema, fruits schema and user schema. I split them in 2 different collection, but a fruit schema can have a reference to a user.

```
const FruitSchema = new Schema({
  title: {
    type: String
  },
  buyer: {
    _id: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      default: null
    }
  }
})

const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String
  },
  age: {
    type: Number
  },
  gender: {
    type: String
  }
})
```

How would you query all fruits with the user info? What I can think of is find all fruits, get the buyer._id then find each user, map them back the fruit array, sounds so tedious and complicated. If it's mysql I just JOIN.

Comment: You can use lookup or populate if using mongoose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `$lookup` to join buyer id with user id, for all matching collections, it will return the user info as an embedded document

```
db.fruitz.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $lookup : {
                from : "userz",
                localField : "buyer_id",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as : "buyerInfo"
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

fruits collection

```
> db.fruitz.find().pretty()
{ "_id" : 2, "title" : "apple", "buyer_id" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 1, "title" : "banana", "buyer_id" : 2 }
```

users collection

```
> db.userz.find().pretty()
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "abc", "age" : 20, "gender" : "M" }
>
```

$lookup aggregate

```
> db.fruitz.aggregate( [ { $lookup : { from : "userz", localField : "buyer_id", foreignField: "_id", as : "buyerInfo" } } ] ).pretty()
```

output

```
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "title" : "apple",
    "buyer_id" : 1,
    "buyerInfo" : [
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "name" : "abc",
            "age" : 20,
            "gender" : "M"
        }
    ]
}
{ "_id" : 1, "title" : "banana", "buyer_id" : 2, "buyerInfo" : [ ] }
>
```

Comment: this is a good answer but buyerInfo can be object instead of an array? Suppose one product can only have one buyer.

Comment: found the answer, `{$unwind: '$applicant'}`, thanks sir for this answer!

Comment: yes, you need to `$unwind`, also you can change buyerInfo to object in `$project` pipeline

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB Provides $lookup to join records from two collections:

In your case you can join fruits and user using [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#lookup-aggregation):

```
db.fruits.aggregate([
   {
     $lookup:
       {
         from: "fruits",
         localField: "buyer",
         foreignField: "_id",
         as: "buyer_info"
       }
  }
])
```

[$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#specify-multiple-join-conditions-with-lookup) hat got more powerful in 3.6(if you're using 3.6) which allows adding expressions and on the things you're joining from right collection

Comment: thanks! $populate vs $lookup what is the differences?